# Image inside TouchableOpacity is not clickable in iOS

Tags: image, react-native, touchableopacity

Following is my code

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'pink', height: 100, width: 100}} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => console.log('On Press'}>
     <Image source={} style={{height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 25} imageType ={'profilePhoto'}/> />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

`TouchableOpacity's` size is bigger than the`Image`. If I touch outside of `Image` then `onPress` is working. But If I touch over the `Image` then `onPress` is not firing.

This is happening only in `iOS`. Working as expected in `Android`. I am using `RN0.63`

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an unofficial Image component. Any nested `Touchable` or other gesture component in it will affect your click results.
Try to use the [official Image component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image). Or read the docs of the component you are using. It may has its own `onPress` event.

Comment: I am using official `Image` component only -- `import { Image } from 'react-native'`

Comment: I put your code in my sample project and it works properly (after fix some typo errors in your code). I touched the image and ```On Press``` seems in my console. The correct code is: ```<TouchableOpacity
        style={{backgroundColor: 'pink', height: 100, width: 100}}
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        onPress={() => console.log('On Press')}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: ImageUrl}}
          style={{height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 25}}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>```